# Bootstrap columns displaying photos

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am writing basic code for a beginner site. I am posting some photos and wanted to use columns to display.

When I view my page, all the pics are in one vertical line. How do I get them to display in columns of 3 across the page. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is the HTML/CSS I have written:

HTML:

```
<div class="supporting-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Kevin's Website\Images/My-Love.jpg" style="width: 256px; height: 256px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Kevin's Website\Images/Me-Hayley.jpg" style="width: 256px; height: 256px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Kevin's Website\Images/Me-Mom-Dad.jpg" style="width: 256px; height: 256px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Kevin's Website\Images/Chris-Melissa.jpg" style="width: 256px; height: 256px;">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Kevin's Website\Images/Best-Friends.jpg" style="width: 256px; height: 256px;">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="thumbnail">
         <img src="C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Kevin's Website\Images/Sugar.jpg" style="width: 256px; height: 256px;">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.supporting-4 .thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you adding `bootstrap.css` to your project? - You need to link `bootstrap.css`, something like this:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

plus, you can use `img-responsive` in `img` so you can have images responsive.

**NOTE:** don't use inline-style in `img`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/800" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/800" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/800" >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-4">
       <div class="thumbnail">
         <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/800">
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">
       <div class="thumbnail">
         <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/800" >
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">
       <div class="thumbnail">
         <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/800" >
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help. I knew I was missing something simple.